# Exporting spatial correlograms

Tags: geoda

Is there a way to export spatial correlograms produced in GeoDa as a pdf without taking a screenshot (that would look a bit unprofessional in the paper I am writing)?

Comment: Can't see it - you could ask as an issue in the GeoDa github issue tracker, there's one or two mentions of exporting non-maps to vector formats (SVG and PDF) but no solutions.

Comment: @Spacedman I have done that. Can you recommend other GIS programmes to produce spatial correlograms? Maybe in QGis?

Comment: I'd code something up in R or Python - not sure if there's something to produce the exact same plot as GeoDa though but it could be built. And then exported as PDF no problem.